# NiMH battery charger - purchased module or homemade?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, nimh

I would like to get to a cheap way of charging NiMH batteries.

Are there any suitable modules that could one purchase or should I rather focus on creating one at home?

What are the pros and cons of either way?

Comment: It is not reliable and I will not advice you to use it. There is compatibility issues...

Comment: can you please brief your answer. Which are the parameters which are complaint to the requirement and which else aren't?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not. All the specifications point to the fact that it is to be used with 1S Li-ion or LiPo batteries only regardless of whatever garbage may have been tossed into the title.

Comment: Ok, so is there any module out there that could be used?